# Is there a easy way to handle input type="number" as a default negative value?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I've tried filling the value on init with a "-" sign but only got the Error-Message:

```
The specified value "-" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.
```

Another attempt was to just accept every value as negative if it doesn't start with a "+" sign but when reading the value property the sign wasn't included.

Does anyone know an easy way to handle an input type="number" as a negative and only make it positive when explicitly stated?

Preferably in a user-friendly way. I don't want a check-box to handle that.

**Specifics:**

i have an input Field in html

```
  <input type="number" #testAmount>
```

I want to handle the value as negative when not explicitly stated otherwise.

so my first attempt was this in TS:

```
@ViewChild('testAmount') testAmount: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined = undefined;

  ngOnInit() {
    if(!!this.testAmount){
      console.log('set amount value');
      console.log(this.testAmount.nativeElement.value);
      this.testAmount.nativeElement.value = '-'
    }
  }
```

that's when i got the error message above:

```
The specified value "-" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.
```

**Attempt 2:**

In my second attempt figured to just accept any value and treat it as negative and only once the user puts a "+" before the value it would be a positive.

but that didn't work out, because when i read the value like this:

```
console.log(this.testAmount.nativeElement.value)
```

i was given the value without the + sign, presumably because it was interpreted as a number and thus the + sign was automatically removed.

**To Be clear**
All i want is that the user doesn't have to add the minus sign every time he adds a value, because negative values will be the norm.

But a positive value shall still be possible it is just rather rare.

**Solution?**

Best solution i've found so far is to give my input a KeyDown event and handle the very first key-input, it's not perfect but i think it'll get the job done most of the time:

```
  inputHasBeenMade = false

  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(!this.inputHasBeenMade && !!this.amount){
      if(event.key !== "+"){
        event.preventDefault()
        this.amount.nativeElement.value = '-' + event.key
      }
      this.inputHasBeenMade = true
    }
  }
```

i don't think it's a good solution so i won't write it down as an answer (for now) in the hopes that someone will come up with a better solution.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide example code to show what  you have tried.

Comment: template driven forms? or reactive forms?

Comment: @Yogi i've profided more detail, i hope helps.

Comment: @YosiLeibman I'm not quite certain, it's a simple angular component with minimalistic usage of anything else.

Comment: Make the value a integer rather than a string. `let value = -24; ` will return a int .

Comment: Do you actually need `type="number"`? Consider using `type="text"` with `inputmode="numeric"` instead.

Comment: i didn't knew this was an option thanks. problem is on desktop users can still put in any string, so now i either have to handle that or i use the "fix" i've figured out and so far i'm not really happy with either. they both work, but feel more like work arounds. 

I hoped someone would know a simple solution to what i thought was a common problem, but if it can't be helped i'll stick with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

type number can't have a "-" string.
you can specify -78 or some other number without the `""`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
let myValue = '-';
this.testAmount.nativeElement.value = myValue
```

To

```
  let myValue = -5;
  this.testAmount.nativeElement.value = myValue;
```

You are creating a `minus` symbol when you wrap it with a single `'` or a `"` double quote, and this makes it a string. Remove the quotes and it will be an integer.

You can also look at casting a string to an int if that's required, but not good practice.

Comment: but i don't want to start it at -5 i just want the sign to be there at the beginning so it is a negative value without more user input needed, and only when the user deletes the minus sign it becomes positive. this is because most inputs will be negative and positive inputs will be the exception.

Comment: Then I would probably append the - to the number, and cast it as an int then do some validation that its actually an int then run it.

Comment: how would you handle the inputs you want to be explicitly to be positive? the user can add a + sign in front of the number but i can't read it, because once i read the value the + sign was already filtered out.

Comment: I would do a switch case and identify if the incoming value is + or -, then from there I would likely set a boolean to trigger on my side if I want to append a - to the value, or leave it a positive number. I would likely also have a final int value that would house my expected end result.